# Android Finding the zip code

Tags: java, android, geocoding, reverse-geocoding, zipcode

I want to get the zipcode of a user for my app and have been doing some research on what to do and this seems to be what most people recommend to do. For some reason though I always get a null set of long and lat points. Is there something else I can do or could try. Thank you in advanced

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); 
Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

Becomes null here...

```
double longitude = location.getLongitude();
double latitude = location.getLatitude();
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(longitude,latitude,1);
```

And if I manually add points I still get null here...

```
zip = (addresses.get(0).getPostalCode());
```

Comment: I've found that online services work the best. Googles free service seemed to do alright albeit not the most accurate. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/

Comment: Your `LocationManager` code will rarely work, simply because the GPS radio is rarely on.